# Activity doesn't refresh layout in onCreate()

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity, picasso

I was creating an application with login to Facebook Based on two activities , once logged on to the second step activity and load the info. The problem is that when I load the images with Picasso I just log in twice before the image appears.
I put the code for Picasso in onCreate , onStart , onResume but does not load the image at the first login of the second activity.
Please help me guys.
This is code:

```
Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(personPhotoUrl).into(avatar);
```

This is second activity

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    if(Start.SignWithFacebook == true)
    {
        name.setText(FacebookLogin.NameFace);
        desc.setText(FacebookLogin.EmailFace);
        try
        {
            Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load("https://graph.facebook.com/" + FacebookLogin.idFacebook + "/picture?type=large").into(avatar);
        }catch(Exception e){}
    }
}
```

This is main activity when call start of second activity:

```
        public void onClick(View v) {
        if(v.getId() == R.id.authButton) {
            if(SignWithFacebook == true)
            {
            Intent second = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
            startActivity(second);
            this.finish();
            }
            else
            {
            SignWithFacebook = true;
            Intent face = new Intent(this, FacebookLogin.class);
            startActivity(face);
            }
        }
```

This is FacebookActivity:

```
    public class FacebookLogin extends Activity {
    private String TAG = "Start";
    public static String NameFace;
    public static String idFacebook;
    public static String EmailFace;
    public static CallbackManager callbackManager;
    private String id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String email;
    ProfileTracker profileTracker;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
        Start.mBut.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("public_profile", "email", "user_friends"));
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        Start.mBut.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                    GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                            loginResult.getAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                                @Override
                                public void onCompleted(JSONObject user, GraphResponse response) {
                                    if (response.getError() != null) {
                                        // handle error
                                    } else {
                                        Start.SignWithFacebook = true;
                                        id = user.optString("id");
                                        firstName = user.optString("first_name");
                                        lastName = user.optString("last_name");
                                        email = user.optString("email");
                                        Log.i(TAG,"User ID "+ id);
                                        EmailFace = "" + email;
                                        Log.i(TAG,"Email "+ email);
                                        Start.text.setText("" + email);
                                        idFacebook = id;
                                    }
                                    NameFace = firstName + " " + lastName;
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Log in with " + NameFace, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }
                            }).executeAsync();
            }

                @Override
                public void onCancel() {
                    Start.SignWithFacebook = false;
            }

                @Override
                public void onError(FacebookException exception) {

            }
        });
}

    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

    }

     @Override
     public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
         super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
     }

     public void onResume()
     {
         super.onResume();
        finish();

     }
}
```

Comment: What did you mean by log in twice?
Possible cause: your url is not valid at the first time. Or if your url is valid then it is possible that Picasso is still loading the image but you are thinking that Picasso is not loading it. By the second time of login, Picasso is finished with loading the image

Comment: In either way your provided informationare insufficient. Post where did you use this code snippet, what is the value of photourl, do you see any exception in logtrace?

Comment: I mean that I have to get twice the Activity to see the loaded image .
So how could I initialize the activity at the end of the loading of the image of Picasso ?

Comment: No No exception because even if the Activity main load the image without going to the second I see the image

Comment: Again what are you meaning by "I have to get twice the Activity" ?

Comment: load twice the activity, ie go out in the first and fall within the second

Comment: so basically you are staring the SecondActivity one time when if(SignWithFacebook == true) , right? so can you now describe when does the image load properly? Sorry I am still being unable to understand your scenario. and is "https://graph.facebook.com/" + FacebookLogin.idFacebook + "/picture?type=large" this url is a file url? if it is not a file url then it shouldn't work

Comment: do you see proper desired value in name & desc textview?

Comment: you are setting "avatar" as target, but where did you referenced it? e.g. ImageView avatar = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.your_id_value); ? and due to your coding you wouldn't be able to see any exception in  your logcat, cause you are consuming the exception. change the catch block into-
catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}

Comment: Yyou may not have written , but there is in the original avatar = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.avatar); because the second time I see the image

Comment: change the catch block into-
catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}

Comment: and then ? What should I write the log ?

Comment: with this changed catch block, run and look into logcat for any exception trace.

Comment: Thank you so much practically the id that comes back from facebook is null ..
E / Error : https://graph.facebook.com/null/picture?type=large

Comment: as your problem is solved, could you accept my answer?

Comment: you , but I do not understand why the String id is not supported Although Call In Method onCompleted of FacebookLogin, it's strange

Comment: FacebookLogin.idFacebook is null value. Did you save the id in the static variable properly?

Comment: Add this Toast after NameFace = firstName + " " + lastName; line. ANd see what is the id you get.

Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Log in with id:  " + idFacebook, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

Comment: Yeah, the toast return id...

Comment: what is the value of the id?

Comment: my id of course , the format is 4930384839239

Comment: you are invoking  finish(); in your onResume(), so your FacebookLogin activity instance is getting destroyed, so you are returning to your MainActivity, then you are pressing your R.id.authButton button? going to SecondActivity and finding the idFacebook null? am I correct?

Comment: When the facebookLogin activity finish the app return on the mainActivity and check the bool, if is true start secondactivity. I call finish(); because the facebook activity don't finish so is necessary to invoke finish() method to return at mainActivity

Comment: ok, but when you are calling finish() and returning to MainActivity, by that time is your idFacebook assigned properly?

Comment: Certainly because only the first time that I run SecondActivty returns null , if I go out from facebook , and step back to the second activity the second time it works , even if the second activity will run a third activity and revision to the second the photo appears..

Comment: just a wild guess now, as onCompleted() will be invoked from different thread [ due to executeAsync() ], there is some strange issues if static variables are updated from different thread (e.g does not guaranty latest value cross threads ) . Don't know if that is the case. wish you all the best.

Comment: It can be , thanks for everything , I will wait more answers

Comment: But the toast wich we test work correctly...I don't know...

Comment: I can suggest two different last try to check if my last wild guess were eligible. 
1. idFacebook = id; change this to FacebookLogin.idFacebook = id;
Or
2. public static String idFacebook; change this to public static volatile String idFacebook;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must download the image `Synchronously`:

```
Bitmap imageBitmap =  Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load("https://graph.facebook.com/" + FacebookLogin.idFacebook + "/picture?type=large").get()
```

And after, you can set the image:

```
ImageView myImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myImageView);
myImageView.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
```

NB: You must use `AsyncTask` to do this.

Comment: Works !, not perfectly but it works , I have a question for you : when the method is called finish () ; all variables are " destroyed " ?

Answer (score 0):

As per our discussion with OP in the comments, the image url is wrong, as you are getting `"graph.facebook.com/null/picture?type=large"` as url at the first time due to `FacebookLogin.idFacebook`'s `null` value

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: we  had long discussion in comments, and based on our investigation, we found the cause of the problem. I just didn't bother to describe here all the discussion we already had in the comments.

Comment: The answer should be self-contained, please include the relevant information and / or code.